# javascript array serializing

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have such code. The main problem is that `var jsonOfLog = JSON.stringify(data);` gives correct JSON `"[{"name":"Jhon"},{"name":"Nick"},{"name":"Sanders"}]"` but `var jsonOfLog = JSON.stringify(test);` gives `undefined`.

Why? It's problem with types or something else? How to fix this?

```
function AppViewModel() {

    self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.addItems = function () {
        self.items.push({ Name: 'Test', Date: 'Test', Time: 'Test'});
    }
    function time_format(d) {
        hours = format_two_digits(d.getHours());
        minutes = format_two_digits(d.getMinutes());
        seconds = format_two_digits(d.getSeconds());
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
    function format_two_digits(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
    }
    self.save = function () {
        data = [{ name: 'Jhon' }, { name: 'Nick' }, { name: 'Sanders' }];
        var test = self.items;
        var jsonOfLog = JSON.stringify(test);

        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            url: "ConvertLogInfoToXml",
            data: "jsonOfLog=" + jsonOfLog,
            success: function (returnPayload) {
                console && console.log("request succeeded");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console && console.log("request failed");
            },

            processData: false,
            async: false
        });
    }
    self.capitalizeLastName = function () {
        debugger;

        var date = $("#date").val();


        $.ajax({
            cache: false,

            type: "GET",

            url: "GetByDate",

            data: { "date": date },

            success: function (data) {

                var result = "";

                $.each(data, function (id, item) {
                    var tempDate = new Date();
                    var tempTime = item.Time;
                    debugger;
                    tempDate =new Date(parseInt(item.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                    self.items.push({ Name: item.Name, Date: (tempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + tempDate .getDate() + '/' + tempDate.getFullYear(), Time: tempTime.Hours });
                });
            },

            error: function (response) {
                debugger;
                alert('eror');
            }
        });

    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: what does console.log(self.items) output?

Comment: Shouldn't your `AppViewModel` function have a `return`?

Comment: @Quantastical What does a constructor function need a return value for?

Comment: @Tomalak I was thinking they had just called `AppViewModel()` and passed the return into the `ko.applyBindings` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple things in your code that could be causing the problem.

First, the `test` variable is a reference to `self.items`, which is a Knockout `observableArray` and not a native JavaScript array. I'm not very familiar with Knockout, but that may not serialize as an array.

Also, on the first line of your constructor function, you are assigning to `self` without using `var`. This is assigning a value to a global variable instead of a local. If you have a similar construct elsewhere in your code, it is likely that the `self` reference is getting overwritten.

Comment: *"that may not serialize as an array"* It doesn't. Knockout observables are functions, you get the array they contain when you call them (`var test = self.items();`). But that's by far not the only problem in the OP's code...

Comment: @Tomalak you are right! Thanks! Write answer i will accep it.

Comment: @A191919 Please be sure to fix the missing `var` issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stringify an observable array like that; you end up stringifying the function and not the array. You should be using the `ko.toJSON(viewModel)` function for that.

Remember, in KnockOut, you always need to use the `object.myObservableValue()` to access the actual value of the observable (instead of `object.myObservableValue`), otherwise you end up using the function instead of the value.

Comment: I would not use `ko.toJSON()` here. Simply unwrapping the value and let jQuery do the JSON handling is the cleaner approach.